# JSON Schema Validation Duplicate Key Elements

Tags: java, json, spring, validation, schema

My Schema;

```
{
"title": "Reporting Schema",
"type": "object", 
"properties":  {    
   "id" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 1, "maxLength":25 },
   "firstName" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":25 },
   "middleName" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":25 },
   "lastName" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":25 },
   "companyName" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":70 },
   "address1" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":50 },
   "address2" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":50 },
   "city" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":20 },
   "state" : {"type": "string", "minLength": 0, "maxLength":2 }
},
"required": [ "id"],
"additionalProperties": false
}
```

My data to test; You can see it has multiple firstName Values.

```
{
"id" : "SchemaTest",

"firstName" : "D",
"firstName" : "D",
"firstName" : "D",

"middleName" : "M",
"lastName" : "Bro",
"companyName" : "",
"address1" : "Test_Address_One",
"address2" : "Test_Address_Two",
"city" : "City_Name",
"state" : "US"
}
```

Is it possible to have my schema validate that the data isn't matching the schema contract and have it flag a false validation?

I'm thinking there might be an option in the *addtionalProperties* section.

Comment: What language/script are you using for validation? Do you have something you tried but couldn't achieve the desired result?

Comment: Java spring for a restful web service. I've been using http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ and pasting my schema and data in to begin with but since it validates when I think it shouldn't I'm not sure schema validation is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema can only work with valid JSON.

This is not valid JSON; you can't have more than one key with the same name (e.g. `firstName`), so this won't even reach JSON Schema.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// JavaScript objects cannot have duplicate keys. The keys must all be unique.
console.log(
  "Object :>> ",
  JSON.stringify({
    id: "SchemaTest",
    firstName: "D",
    firstName: "D",
    firstName: "D",
    middleName: "M",
    lastName: "Bro",
    companyName: "",
    address1: "Test_Address_One",
    address2: "Test_Address_Two",
    city: "City_Name",
    state: "US",
  }, null, 2)
);
```